# How to return name list using excel formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Data is:

```
-|-A--|-B-|
1|BAT | 5 |
2|CAT | 2 |
3|RAT | 4 |
```

I want formula that gives name list of animal if value in columns B > 3.
From example Result is BAT,RAT.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of the approach using you can get what you looking for. BUT you need to use VBA help to achieve this by creating user defined function.

To implement user defined function in excel:

```
1. Press Alt-F11 to open visual basic editor
2. Click Module on the Insert menu
3. Copy and paste below metioned user defined function
4. Exit visual basic editor
```

Here is the function:

```
Function Lookup_concat(Search_in_col As Range, Return_val_col As Range)

    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String

    For i = 1 To Search_in_col.Count
        If Search_in_col.Cells(i, 1) > 3 Then
            If result = "" Then
                result = Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value
            Else
                result = result & ", " & Return_val_col.Cells(i, 1).Value
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Lookup_concat = Trim(result)

End Function
```

And now in cell C1, paste the formula:

```
=Lookup_concat(B2:B4,A2:A4)
```

And this will return **`BAT, RAT`**.

Explaination of user defined function:
Lookup_concat(Search_in_column, Concatenate_values_in_column)
Looks for a value which is greater than 3 in a column and then returns values in the same rows from a column you specify, concatenated into a single cell.

Answer (score 0):

Following the VB approach as smartly suggested by @Nelly27281, I propose the following function with works with variables for the criteria, range, input and output columns making it more flexible.

```
'Variables  Type     Description                                                          Sample
'sCriteria  String   The criteria to search for                                           “>3”
'rInput     Range    The whole range to work with                                         A1:B4
'bColSearch Byte     Column within the rInput range to search for using “sCriteria”       2
'bColOutput Byte     Column within the rInput range to obtain the output value            1
'blHasHdr   Boolean  (Optional) True if the “rinput” range has header, default is false   1

Public Function rSearch_sOutput(sCriteria As String, _
    rInput As Range, bColSearch As Byte, bColOutput As Byte, Optional blHasHdr As Boolean)
Dim sOutput As String
Dim L As Long, L0 As Long

    Rem Set Output String
    L0 = IIf(blHasHdr, 2, 1)
    With rInput
        For L = L0 To .Rows.Count
            If Application.Evaluate(.Columns(bColSearch).Cells(L).Value2 & sCriteria) Then
                If sOutput = Empty Then
                    sOutput = .Columns(bColOutput).Cells(L).Value2
                Else
                    sOutput = sOutput & ", " & .Columns(bColOutput).Cells(L).Value2
    End If: End If: Next: End With

    Rem Set Results
    rSearch_sOutput = sOutput

End Function
```

To use it enter the following formula:

```
=rSearch_sOutput(">3",A1:B4,2,1,1)
```